# Keep build folder files for each build (Vite / SvelteKit)

Tags: vite, sveltekit

When using Vite (SvelteKit) there's a hash appended to filenames when building so that the file is unique based on its contents (for example: `_page.svelte-8f3ed184.js`).

Currently when I run the `vite build` (or `npm run build`) the new files are built but the old files are cleared from the build folder. I would like to keep all files in the build folder on each built so that users that are currently browsing the site can still retrieve the previous build until the next time they come to the site (which would load the newer built).

Is there a setting for this in Vite? I haven't been able to find it.

### Example

##### Build 1

```
"+page.svelte" file creates _page.svelte-8f3ed184.js
```

##### Build 2 ("+page.svelte" file was modified)

```
"+page.svelte" file creates _page.svelte-9j2dus3s.js
```

##### Currently after Build 2 only the second file is in the folder:

```
ls build/client/_app/immutable/components/pages/question
_page.svelte-9j2dus3s.js
```

##### What I'm looking for is after Build 2 both files are in the folder:

```
ls build/client/_app/immutable/components/pages/question
_page.svelte-8f3ed184.js
_page.svelte-9j2dus3s.js
```